# Minimum AND operation on subset

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given an array of size N .

Let's create all the subsets of this array which contain at least 2 elements. Now, operate AND over the elements of each subset, and store the results in a new array.

I need  to find out the minimum value of this new array.

Example : N=3 and array be {1,2,3}

Then answer is 0 as Possible Subset : (1,2) , (1,3) , (2,3) , (1,2,3) : Minimum value from

{( 1&2 ) , ( 1&3 ) ,( 2&3 ) , ( 1&2&3 )}  =  Minimum value from { 0,1,2,0 } is 0.

Main problem is N is upto 10^5 so we cant generate all subsets.So please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The lowest value will be when you AND all elements in the array.  Each extra element will either leave it unchanged or lower it, so bring in all the elements.